# How to combine a key: list-value dict to a list of key:value in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-filter

I have this dictionary:

```json
{
  "key1": [
    "value1",
    "value2"
  ],
  "key2": [
    "value3"
  ]
}
```

I'd like to have this result:

```json
[
  {"key1": "value1"},
  {"key1": "value2"},
  {"key2": "value3"}
]
```

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of the filters [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists) and [`subelements`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements) in order to achieve this.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
        list: "{{ list | default([]) + [{ item.0.key: item.1 }] }}"
      loop: "{{ dict | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"
      vars: 
        dict:
          key1:
            - value1
            - value2
          key2:
            - value3
    
    - debug:
        var: list
```

This will yield the recap:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'key1', 'value': ['value1', 'value2']}, 'value1'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'key1', 'value': ['value1', 'value2']}, 'value2'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'key': 'key2', 'value': ['value3']}, 'value3'])

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "list": [
        {
            "key1": "value1"
        },
        {
            "key1": "value2"
        },
        {
            "key2": "value3"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Nice. I had try this combination of filters but didn't see I had everything I need in its output. Thanks.